# Non-blocking stdio

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, nonblocking

I'm working on a program which will be taking in user input from the console as well as printfing out in a separate thread. I want to avoid situations where the user is halfway through typing something in and a printf comes along and prints itself at the cursor.

Is there a way to do non-blocking io in c from the console window? Ideally, capturing keypresses or something like that such that what the user types doesn't appear on the screen. I'm developing in Ubuntu, and it's best if I don't have to use things like ncurses.

Answer (score 5):

using `termios` you can disable terminal echoing:

```
#include <termios.h>

struct termios oflags, nflags;
tcgetattr(fileno(stdin), &oflags);
nflags = oflags;
nflags.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
nflags.c_lflag |= ECHONL;

if (tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &nflags) != 0) {
    /* handle error */
}
```

then before exit (use `atexit`) you must restore the terminal:

```
if (tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &oflags) != 0) {
    /* handle error */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Why `ECHONL`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to turn off echo from C, taken directly from [an HP forum](http://forums11.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?admit=109447626+1250224162922+28353475&threadId=380786) (and I haven't personally tested it):

> Okay this should be a simple example
>   of turning off echo:
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <unistd.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
> #include <termios.h>
>
> #define STDIN_FDES 0
>
> struct termios save;
>
> int main(int argc, char *argv[])
> {
> int cc = 0;
> char s_tmp[80],*p = NULL;
> struct termios work;
>
> cc = tcgetattr(STDIN_FDES,&save);
> work = save;
> work.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO);
> cc = tcsetattr(STDIN_FDES,TCSANOW,&work);
> (void) printf("\nEnter value: ");
> (void) fflush(stdout);
> p = fgets(s_tmp,sizeof(s_tmp),stdin);
> if (p != NULL) (void) printf("Out -> %s\n",p);
> cc = tcsetattr(STDIN_FDES,TCSANOW,&save);
> return(cc);
> }
> ```
>
> NOTE: It is very important that you
>   have signal handlers to catch SIGINT,
>   SIGTERM, ... and reset the terminal
>   using the original termios because the
>   last tcsetattr() wins and this applies
>   to the terminal device NOT simply the
>   process. If you leave the process with
>   echo off, it will be off in the shell
>   as well.

Otherwise, if Bash is a suitable approach, apparently you can just do [`stty -echo`](http://rcsg-gsir.imsb-dsgi.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/documents/bourne/node46.html).

Answer (score 0):

Turning off echo or using non-blocking I/O isn't the answer, if I understand your question correctly.  Rather, you want to prevent a background thread from interrupting a user input thread, right?

For that, you'll need access to raw keypresses instead of line-buffered input. I don't know why you're allergic to ncurses or similar libraries; that's what they're for!  I guess you could do it with termios or ioctl calls, if that's how you roll....

But to solve your multi-threaded TTY output problem, you could do this:

1) Create a mutex to control who can access the console

**In the background thread**, to output a message:

Grab the mutex; write the message; release the mutex; go back to sleep!

**In the user input thread:**

Grab the mutex when new input is detected. Keep exclusive access until the user hits enter,
then release the mutex and give the background thread a chance to talk.

Does that help?

Comment: Take a look at cfmakeraw() for raw terminal mode.  Be sure to save the termios structure before calling this function so you can restore it when you're done.