# Make c++ not wait for user input

Tags: c++, input, chat, winsock, winsock2

So, i am trying to make a c++ WinSock2 chatter, just for learning.
It is a console application and i want to take user input (for sending to the counterpart), but i still want to be able to recive. (so you can write a message while still being able to recive one)...

When using `cin >> input;` the program "pauses" until the user has enterd something, that way it is "turn based" (one user writes something and sends it, then the other user writes something and sends it).

Is there a way to make the user be able to write something WHILE the recive stuff is still running? (Preferably something else than multi threading)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/6736536/1938163. You should probably manage your own buffers from different threads (and handle the synchronization yourself).

Comment: A separate thread is likely an overkill. You need event (de)multiplexing.

Answer (score 4):

What about checking if buffer isn't empty? But code wouldn't be really portable then, because you need to make some system calls as I know. See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/86211/).
But maybe you can do it with some C code, I'll do some research and update my answer.

UPD: Ok, I did it. What you need is [select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28Unix%29) function.
It could wait till `stdin` is ready for read, and that's what we need.
But looks like it don't work with C++ streams, so you need to use only C code for reading.

Let's jump to definition:
`int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds, fd_set *errorfds, struct timeval *timeout)`

Ok, we need to check only read buffer, so `writefds` and `errorfds` could be `NULL`. And we need to check only `stdin`, so `nfds` is `1` (number of `fds`es)

What about timeout? It's should be `0`, so we need to initialize variable `struct timeval timeout` and set seconds and nanoseconds to 0 by `timeout.tv_sec = 0` and `timeout.tv_usec = 0`.

So, only `readfds` left. It's pretty simple too: we need to initialize variable, "zero" it, and add `stdin`.
It can be done with `fd_set readfds`, `FD_ZERO(&readfds)` and `FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &readfds)`.

Okay, final step: function call. It should be `select(1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout)`.

This would return `0` if input buffer is empty and `1` if it's not.

UPD2: Looks like it's not C++ streams, something strange happens and it breaks when buffer is empty at very first call. I'll try to catch the problem.

UPD3: Ok, Now I figured it out. Looks like you can use `select` with C++ streams.

`Select` has VERY strange (IMHO) feature: it resets `readfds`. I'm not sure how to prevent It from doing this, so I just used one more `fd_set` variable to hold it, so you need to add `fd_set savefds = readfds` after `readfds` initialization, and `readfds = savefds` after each call. That's awful solution, but I don't know how could I improve it.

**So code is:**

*Initialization:*

```
fd_set readfds;
FD_ZERO(&readfds);
FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &readfds);
fd_set savefds = readfds;
```

*Timeout initialization:*

```
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 0;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;
```

*And usage:*

```
if (select(1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout)) {
  cin >> input;
  send(input);
}
readfds = savefds;
```

UPD4: Don't forget to include `unistd.h` and `cstdlib`

Comment: The only "multiplatform" api I know of is `select`. And the windows implementation is... lacking to say the least. I'd say using `std::thread` with some basic sync and callbacks should do the job.

Comment: You could also check sockets with `select` too, so it's really best solution IMHO

Comment: This is a windows (WinSock) question, and you're not sharing windows-compatible code. Even if I swapped out `STDIN_FILENO` for its actual value, I still get an unresolved external symbol error when actually trying to use `select` as-written, and there is no `unistd.h` for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34479916/10588679) is quite helpful.

Here is an example (base code taken from [SELECT man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
  fd_set rfds, save_rfds;
  struct timeval tv;
  int retval;

  /* Watch stdin (fd 0) to see when it has input. */
  FD_ZERO(&rfds);
  FD_SET(0, &rfds);

  /* Make a copy of rfds, as after running select, it gets reset */
  save_rfds = rfds;

  /* Wait for zero seconds. */
  tv.tv_sec = 0;
  tv.tv_usec = 0;

  while(true){

    retval = select(1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    rfds = save_rfds;

    if (retval == -1)
      perror("select()");
    else if (retval){
      /* Runs as soon as you enter a value and press enter. */

      std::cout<<"Data is available now.\n";

      std::string s;
      getline(std::cin, s);
      std::cout<<"Data Input: "<<s<<"\n";

      /* FD_ISSET(0, &rfds) will be true. */
    }
  }

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```