# C++ console application async accepting user input

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I recently stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736536/c-input-and-output-to-the-console-window-at-the-same-time)
link and I just tried it, but it's not working as I expect.

With this code:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void ReadCin(std::atomic<bool>& run)
{
    std::string buffer;

    while (run.load())
    {
        std::cin >> buffer;
        if (buffer == "q")
        {
            run.store(false);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::atomic<bool> run(true);
    std::thread cinThread(ReadCin, std::ref(run));

    while (run.load())
    {
        // some lengthy operation
    }

    run.store(false);
    cinThread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

In the main While loop, I have an object of a class that is doing some lengthy operation, one which I'm trying to stop with the letter "q" coming from the user. When I type "q", i see the "run.store(false);" hit in the ReadCin method, but this doesn't break me off from the main while loop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Case, then add a break in that block. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/159985/

Comment: Are you sure that your "some lengthy operation" is short enough to let the main while loop check the value of run? Maybe this operation is freezing the while loop, no?

Comment: Might want to look at signals. Ctrl+C is usually used to cancel a long running application (SIGINT is sent in this case).