# using "command line" input along with shown images in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

These are some "windows" shown in the watershed demo of OpenCV package.

Interaction between user and the app includes some simple discrete input characters and I barely see any sort-of command line input.

I'd like to make it just a bit more convenient interaction. something likes:

funcA arg1 arg2Enter 
funcB arg1 ... Enter

after "enter", the command is run

is there anything like that in OpenCV??

[image: watershed demo of OpenCV]

Comment: Qt can be used to make sophisticated GUI. But I'm not having any work with GUI design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying that you want to call a function of your program while the program is running to process the images? For example while the program is running you call `watershed(whatever, arguments)` ?

I don't think that you can do that without some effort. I haven't tried anything like it, but what comes to my mind is using a separate thread to get input and then map that input to a function.

**Edit:** See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171132/non-blocking-console-input-c) answer if indeed this is what you are looking for.

Comment: if you have tried watershed demo or some other demos of OpenCV, you will understand what I mean. simply speaking, while the images are being shown, I'd like to process commands like "funcA arg1 arg2" from the user keyboard input

Comment: I have tried that demo, isn't what you are saying the same with what I wrote? OpenCV doesn't provide you with a way to do that, you can use WaitKey() for a specific key and you have a mouse callback but that's it. If you want that kind of functionality you have to write it yourself.

Comment: So, I have to write another thread to perform that, for example, using TBB?? Is there a simpler way-around?? I've read for a while about TBB and it's likely to be a distant application to me

Comment: if the TBB coding here is simple, please help me more clearly... some coding for example

Comment: I am sorry, but I really cannot help you more with that, I've never used TBB. Since you want that kind of interaction, why don't you reconsider using Qt to create a very simple GUI? You don't even have to incorporate the OpenCV window if you don't want to, you could create just a simple GUI with a button for the function and a couple of textedits for the arguments and then show the images with imshow() as you would with OpenCV.

Comment: I guess I'll have to consider this direction since I already can work on simple Qt and the Qt-OpenCV integration. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

The code for the demo is available with your OpenCV installation.
You can adjust it as you like.

Comment: I mean I don't know how to code such command input: funcA arg1 arg2Enter OR funcB arg1 ... Enter. Any hint?

Comment: The code is written in C/C++. If you cannot write C/C++ then I am afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: the coding is OK. but here I don't know how to approach. This is similar to reading a whole string line funcA arg1 arg2Enter. Enter is to notify command input by user; then, string line is splitted to funcA, arg1 and arg2 to process and call the correct function.