# Is there an alternative to getch(); which won't pause the program?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, ncurses

I'm writing a game currently in ncurses and I have a ship that is controlled by the user and an 'automated' that moves slowly down the lines to kill you. However, I'm using a while loop containing everything and each time I use getch() the loop pauses and waits for input, meaning that the enemy only moves after input from the user.

```
        c=getch(); //causes a pause until a button is pressed before the next action

        if(c==97) //if a is pressed, move position of '*' left
        {
            dir=-1;

        }

        if(c==100) //if d is pressed, move position of '*' right
        {
            dir=1;

        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-blocking console input C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171132/non-blocking-console-input-c)

Comment: The traditional name for this function is kbhit(). Non-blacking detection of keyboard hits, usually for video games purposes.

Comment: @d9ngle: Not really as that is about how to do nonblocking input *without* using curses. With curses, it is much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using curses, just call `nodelay` or `halfdelay` or `timeout` to make `getch` non-blocking, or have it return after a short wait if no key has been pressed.  See the inopts(3ncurses) man page.

Answer (score 0):

Use `poll` on the input file descriptor (0, aka `STDIN_FILENO`) to determine whether there's input pending before you call `getch`. Normally you would poll with a nonzero timeout and then the call doubles as the timing for your game's loop so it runs at a fixed tick rate you control rather than as many iterations per second as the cpu/system load allow.

Comment: If you're using `poll()` or `select()`, then you should also be using non-blocking I/O...

Comment: @Attie: Not necessarily, and almost certainly not with curses.

Comment: @R interesting, could you explain? If you `read()` in the wrong place or one too many times then wouldn't your application still block when using curses? Or do you propose to never read more than one byte per `read()`, and never `read()` more than once per `poll()`/`select()`?

Comment: Having re-read the manpage, I suspect that @Chris's answer is more appropriate (`getch()` appears to be window-aware), and `no-delay` mode should be employed to prevent blocking.