# Nonblocking stdio

Tags: c, io, stdio

I'd like to use `stdio` is a small C program for buffering I/O. It's not exactly *crucial* that I use `stdio` instead of buffering the raw I/O functions myself, but the program is small enough that I would feel dumb to reimplement buffered I/O for it.

However, I would also like to not block when waiting for input. Is there a good way to do this? I'm considering setting `O_NONBLOCK` on the underlying file descriptor, but I'm not sure if this is well-defined on `stdio` files. Isn't there a risk that some `stdio` implementations may decide to consider the `FILE *` permanently broken if the underlying I/O returns an error, or is this just a misunderstanding of mine?

Basically, then: How does one use `stdio` in a well-defined way on an `O_NONBLOCK` stream? If this is not possible, is there some other well-defined way to do non-blocking reads through `stdio`?

Comment: probably you could customize the header file a little bit http://www.gnu.org/software/m68hc11/examples/stdio_8h-source.html

Comment: Maybe not what you are looking for but... threads?

Comment: @rodrigo: Not exactly what I was looking for, indeed. Adding proper synchronization and stuff to this program would be more complex than manually buffering I/O.

Comment: @PhilippBraun: The point of this is to stay somewhat portable with different `stdio` implementations. Otherwise, I'd just do this in some way that happens to work with glibc.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276029/non-blocking-stdio

Comment: @chux: I did see that question, but it seems to have very little overlap with this one, and the answers are just about terminal control.

Comment: You ask about _the underlying I/O_, the behavior of which depends on the kind of device you're reading the input from, so you'd have to name that.